# Trigger to Change Author's Member Group on Channel Status change?

Tags: members, status, groups

Is it possible? Basically the scenario is this:

1) Member in default Member Group submits Channel form to make entry.
2) Entry automatically set to status 'Under Review'
3) Admin reviews and - if necessary - marks 'approved'
4) Author/Member automatically changes group from 'Members' to 'Approved'

Is there anyway of doing this? I'm thinking perhaps not. Looked at Zoo Visitor but don't think it's the right fit. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the status is being changed in the EE control panel?  If so, then this will likely require an extension that uses the entry_submission_end hook:

http://www.ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#entry_submission_end

It's a pretty simple script to just check if the status being submitted is 'approved' and then if it is to update the database with the [EE database class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html) and change the member group to the desired number.